# I want to override the product/price/amount/default.phtml in my custom module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am creating a extension that will be modifying products price across the website. For this I need to override the `product/price/amount/default.phtml`.

What I have tried so far is:

Created a custom module with:

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```

Change the  `default_amount_render_template` path in the code above.

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

Copied this file from the **Magento_Catalog** Module

Made changes but no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently worked on this above requirement.

I will share my suggestion. Please check whether it works for you.

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

And I have written my custom code on

> Vendor/ModuleName/product/price/amount/default.phtml

It works for me.

Comment: Can I see your phtml file, I want to override the phtml file but I need to pull product attribute. If the value I am after is enabled show the price if not don’t show it.